# Execute en sentencias no preparadas

Tags: php

Esta es una pregunta de consulta de conceptos.
Las sentencias preparadas protegen la consulta de sql injection.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories);
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour);
$sth->execute();
```

Pero si no se utilizan valores externos no es necesario usar sentencias preparadas, por eso se usa **Query()** .

```
$sth = $dbh->query('SELECT name, colour FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < 50');
```

Pero no es mejor utilizar ***execute()*** también en sentencias no preparadas en lugar de ***query()***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las sentencias antes de ser procesadas deben ser preparadas, por que en un ambiente de producción van a responder a la interactividad que de el usuario; es decir un select, insert, update o delete dependerán de las variables que mande el usuario:

```
//ejemplo
$enunciado = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM ventas WHERE producto = :producto");
```

Para el caso anterior la respuesta del sistema dependerá de la información que mande el usuario

```
//ejemplo
$enunciado = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM ventas WHERE producto = :producto");
$ejecutar->bindParam(':producto', $producto, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$ejecutar->execute();
```

> Si tu solo estás ejecutando pruebas en local donde no es un ambiente
>   real para tu aplicativo ahi si esta demás; pero generalmente los
>   desarrollos van a producción por lo tanto deben de pasar las
>   sentencias por el método prepare así como identificar los valores que
>   llegan por medio de los apuntadores de posición y al final indicar el
>   tipo de dato que llega

El hecho no va en que sea como tal una opinión de si es mejor o no, si no por el hecho de que las sentencias no solo deben responder a op con la base de datos si no así mismo proteger el usuario que esta usándolas para evitar ataques de inyección SQL

> Si no lo haces estas eliminando la buena práctica de proteger tus
>   consultas SQL, cosa que para cualquier desarrollo deben estar
>   presentes

Te aconsejo que tengas presente que no solo tengas presente execute() o bindParam si no también:

1. PDO::PARAM_STR
2. PDO::PARAM_INT

Para que con lo anterior al momento de hacer bindParam se identifique el tipo de valor que se esta pasando

Comment: Gracias. Mi consulta iba por el tipo de consulta que no son en ambiente de pruebas y que no utilizan parametros externos. Que son consultas internas.

Comment: Si haces las consultas aún sin parámetros debes prepararlas, puesto que la inyección sql aún así se puede dar